# How to using PHP to get a array's name?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm making a page about dict. 
I need to write a loop to foreach them. 
For showing the each title, i need to get the array's name.
(each title's name just is the array's name)

> i have a array here :

```
$a = array('num1', 'num2'); 
$b = array('num1', 'num2');
$c = array('num1', 'num2'); 
$z = array('num1', 'num2');
```

**how to get its name a,b,c,z?**

Comment: put all arrays inside an array and loop through them and echo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do an array:

```
$arrays = array(
   'a' => $a, 
   'b' => $b,
   'c' => $c,
   'd' => $d
);
```

and with a foreach you access their names:

```
foreach($arrays as $array_name => $array) {
   ...
}
```